# Powershell Expand System.Object[] Value and ConvertTo-Csv

Tags: powershell, select-object

I'm making a script which made a RestMethod call and export results to CSV
On the output I have an object which contain the agentstatus and the last agentstatusmessage but for the last one i saw only System.Object[]
How could i expand the value?

Below a snippet of simple code and an example of the output

```
$r = Invoke-RestMethod @param -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing

$r.computers | Select-Object hostName,lastIPUsed,platform,computerStatus | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"hostName","lastIPUsed","platform","computerStatus"

"srv01","10.1.1.2","Red Hat Enterprise 7 (64 bit)","@{agentStatus=active; agentStatusMessages=System.Object[]}"
"srv02","10.1.2.3","CentOS 7 (64 bit)","@{agentStatus=active; agentStatusMessages=System.Object[]}"
"srv03","10.1.2.4","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64 bit)","@{agentStatus=active; agentStatusMessages=System.Object[]}"
```

Expected:

```
"hostName","lastIPUsed","platform","AgentStatus","agentStatusMessages"

"srv01","10.1.1.2","Red Hat Enterprise 7 (64 bit)","active","Managed (Online)"
"srv02","10.1.2.3","CentOS 7 (64 bit)","active","Managed (Online)"
"srv03","10.1.2.4","Microsoft Windows Server 2019 (64 bit)","active","Managed (Online)"
```

Comment: Or export to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), one to create a separate `agentStatus` property (CSV column), and another to create an `agentStatusMessages` property, which additionally requires *explicitly stringifying* the array contained in the original property:

```bash
$r.computers | 
  Select-Object hostName, lastIPUsed, platform,
                @{ Name='agentStatus'; Expression={ $_.computerStatus .agentStatus } },
                @{ Name='agentStatusMessages'; Expression={ $_.computerStatus.agentStatusMessages -join ';' } } | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note:

- Because **neither [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) nor its file-based cousin, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), meaningfully stringify *array*-valued properties**, you **must *decide on* how to represent arrays *as a single string***.
- The above uses `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join), to form a single string from the array-valued `.agentStatusMessages` property, using self-chosen separator `;` - adjust as needed; if there's only *one* element in a given array, the separator doesn't come into play.
- Also, since `.computerStatus.agentStatusMessages` is of type `System.Object[]` (`[object[]]`, in PowerShell terms) rather than an array of *strings*, applying `-join` relies on the *implicit* stringification of each element, which in essence means calling `.ToString()` on each element that isn't already a string.
  If the elements are complex objects rather than strings and their `.ToString()` stringification is unhelpful, you must *explicitly* stringify them, such as by choosing a representative / the property of interest:
  E.g., speaking hypothetically, if the elements of the `.computerStatus.agentStatusMessages` array had a `.Text` property, you could rely on [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract the values and join them:
  `$_.computerStatus.agentStatusMessages.Text -join ';'`